# Java monotonically increasing hash function

Tags: java, math, hashcode, hash-function

Is there implementation for monotonically increasing hash function:

given x,y,z are monotonically increasing the f(x,y,z) will be monotonically increasing ?

*Update*
We can assume x,y,x are positive integers and the method result is `long`

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216538

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Monotonic_keys

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for open source implementation. Bitwise operations will be my second try

Comment: Not only is there no implementation, it's not even possible. Three java positive ints equals 93 bits of input, and a long is 64 bits of output. So you are at war with the pigeonhole principle, an invincible opponent.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: Hashes have never required the input to have the same number of bits as the hash, and yes, you're going to pigeonhole.  I would consider that a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Let me try again. What does it even mean for a triple (x,y,z) to be monotonically increasing?